# Loading images in webview blocking MAIN THREAD despite using multithreading

Tags: iphone, multithreading, uiwebview, grand-central-dispatch, uiwebviewdelegate

I have a html string which contains `<img>` tag with a image URL. I have loaded the html string as follows using grand central dispatch.. But my app stuck till the images fully loaded..help me please
`

```
background=dispatch_queue_create("background_queues", NULL);

dispatch_async(background, ^{    

    [webView loadHTMLString:myDescriptionHTML baseURL:NULL]; });

dispatch_release(background);
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make `UIKit` calls on a background thread. What's the point of this code? If you just call `loadRequest:` on the main thread, it won't block the UI while your image loads.

Comment: i have no other choice..the HTML description is stored in my local database..so i have to call by `loadHTMLString: baseURL:` method..